# python convert string like ['-0.88854965D+02'] to float

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to convert the string like `'-0.88854965D+02'` to float?

`float('-0.88854965D+02')` doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -0.88854965D+02
```

Comment: What number do you expect to get? What's with the `D`?

Comment: Are you sure your format is ok? Common eng form [`float('-0.88854965E+02')`] yields `-88.854965` which seems to be correct answer. D letter is unusual.

Comment: -88.854965; D maybe double precision used in Fortran?

Comment: Yes, E+02 is OK. but the string '-0.88854965D+02' is get from an output which I cann't change it

Comment: Well, if only the 'D' is the problem... `float('-0.88854965D+02'.replace("D", "E"))`

Comment: Yes, it works. float('-0.88854965D+02'.replace("D", "E"))
-88.854965

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `'-0.88854965D+02'` appears to be written as scientific E notation.  If that is the case, then you can use the following one-liner to `replace` the 'D' with 'E', and then convert to a `float`:

```
n = float('-0.88854965D+02'.replace("D", "E"))
print n
-88.854965
```